# silverstripe upload tiff and convert to jpeg

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe

i´m working on a image database build with silverstripe framework. It needs to be able to upload large tiff files and they should be converted to jpeg. is there a build in function to do that, or do I have to use a library for that?
Regards,
Florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SilverStripe doesn't have built-in image conversion utilities, just a [GD](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.0/framework/filesystem/GD.html) class which mainly handles resizing of existing images (in gif/jpg/png).

ImageMagick supports conversion of TIFFs (see [supported formats](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php)). I'm sure you can find PHP wrapper libraries for it (doesn't have to be specific to SilverStripe), or use the commandline tool directly via `exec()`.

Other than that, we have the `UploadField` class to handle uploads. It uses the [jQuery fileupload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) plugin, which supports larger files (although server timeouts and PHP config play a role here as well). You might want to look into [chunked uploads](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Chunked-file-uploads).

Comment: ImageMagick did the trick for me. It was installed on the server (convert). exec('convert ' .$path. " ". $jpegPath, $output);